# Import ASP.NET dll to call ASP.NET Webform into VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I created a simple calculator application in ASP.NET WebForms:

[image]

I am trying to get an ASP.NET DLL used as a reference in a VB.NET.

I got the ASP.NET dll in the `obj` folder and debug in `debug` folder I got the ASP.NET dll:

[image]

but I am not able to call ASP.NET webform

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myobject As calculator2.WebForm1
End Sub
```

Could you help me to fix the problem?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIlJZ.jpg)

Comment: Why are you using WebForms in 2022?

Comment: Thanks for reply Creating for web applications. I have a attendence project. I Created in Asp.net mvc web application my project is in vb.net application so i want to call asp.net project using vb.net button.

Comment: can you explain why you want to reference the WebForm in your code?

Comment: call what? is your vb.net project a "non webform" project? we need more details or we can't help you.

Comment: I have a button in vb.net project when I click the button webborwser will load to display which I created.

Comment: if you want to add first number to the second number you don't need to reference the webform. you can access the value from the first textbox via FirstNumberTextBox.Text (your name might be different like TextBox1.Text)

Comment: Actually the web application working fine but I want to excute  from vb.net button event

Comment: I have added vb.net project form screenshot i want to excute the asp.net application is there any possibulity

Comment: @methushal What you're trying to do is impossible. WebForms assemblies, projects and types have _nothing whatsoever to do_ with controlling the user's web-browser - nor can you run or otherwise "open" them like a desktop application.

Comment: Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim webAddress As String = "https://localhost:44398/Controllers/WebForm1.aspx"
        Process.Start(webAddress)
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Well, a few things.

From your screen shot - that looks like a windows desktop form. And no, they can't be used in web land or for web based.

In fact, VERY counter-intuitive?

What happens if you write this code in a asp.net web form:

we drop a simple button, and text box, and then code behind does this:

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

And our code behind does this:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    TextBox1.Text = "Hello World"

    MsgBox("Hello")

End Sub
```

Well, MsgBox - it is a windows desktop command (I have that reference in this web project).

So, the windows forms? They DIRECT write to the screen on the computer that the code is running. In this case the web server.

In fact, you see this:

User Browser:

[image]

The web server running that dishes out web pages - the server:

[image]

So, any vb "desktop" code? That does not write or work with the web server, but in fact writes to the main console monitor (the web server computer - THAT is where your code is running - not in the web browser).

So, you thus of course can't use nor display "windows" dialog or forms.

In fact you COULD have the code run, and as above shows, we are now stuck, since the web server computer is now waiting for you to click ok on that windows msg box, but that is occuring on the computer up in the cloud or where ever the web server is running. Now, of course when you are developing, then your using one computer - and it is both your web server and also your computer monitor and desktop computer at the same time.

But, keep in mind, anything that is pure windows desktop code and attempts to use windows forms or msg box etc? That code can't be used - since it running on the web server - not the users desktop.

However, you can certainly reference that vb.net desktop program, and you can call + use + consume routies that are "just" routines - without any windows forms code.

So, you might say have dropped a routine in a standard code module, or even say a class module, and then you can referance that project in your asp.net applcation.

So, once done, then class modules, and routines in that desktop applcation can be called and consumed and used in the asp.net applcation. BUT NONE of the code in that desktop applcation that uses or interacts directly with windows forms can be used - only pure code without any user interface can be used.

If you did manage to import or reference code that pops up a windows form? Well then as noted, that form would pop up on the web server computer running the site - not on the end users computer - which of course is a just a browser that consumes and receives web pages from the web server.